# insert column from one table into another

Tags: sql, sqlite

I Have two tables: Set1 and SearchInfo. they look like this:

```
Set1
SearchID | Position
3          1
1          7
3          4

SearchInfo
SearchID | SearchDate
1          6
2          8
3          9
```

I want to add the column Searchdate to Set1 and use SearchID as a key. This is what I have tried:

```
ALTER TABLE Set1 ADD COLUMN SearchDate1 DATETIME;
INSERT INTO Set1 (SearchDate1) SELECT b.SearchDate FROM Set1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN SearchInfo b ON a.SearchID=b.SearchID;
```

However, this is what I get

```
Set1
SearchID | Position | SearchDate1
3          1          
1          7          
3          4
                      x
                      x
                      x
```

as oppose to :

```
Set1
SearchID | Position | SearchDate1
3          1          9
1          7          6
3          4          9
```

Comment: You want an UPDATE, not an INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is : This will update the column you have already made. You do not need to insert anything

```
Update SET1
Set SearchDate = si.SearchDate
From Set1 s
inner join SearchInfo si
where s.SearchID = si.SearchID
```

Comment: this is what I did:UPDATE Set1
Set a.SearchDate1=b.SearchDate
FROM Set1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN SearchInfo b
ON a.SearchID1=b.SearchID
WHERE a.SearchID1=b.SearchID; But I get a syntax error near ".".

Comment: @MAS you do not need Set a.SearchDate1 ... just Set SearchDate1 it will know you mean in Set1 because of the previous line